# Rendering React components from text

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a simple blog/CMS tool. In authoring content, I'm supporting an option to enter raw html/css. The user enters this content into a text area, and I can render this into a page using dangerouslySetInnerHtml. That works fine.

However, I'd really like to embed some React components the content as well. Ideally I'd like to enter something like this into a textarea...

```
<div>
  <p>Some content</p>
  <MyPictureComponent url="..." />
</div>
```

...and then render that into a page and have it create the MyPictureComponent.

I'll be storing the above "code" in a database, and rendering it dynamically as users view the "post". Is it possible to rendering that raw text as functioning React?

I saw this project ([HTML to React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react)), which seemed promising, bu that seems to only parse the HTML given to it, not tags for React components.

Comment: You can render your content [server-side](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html) and send it down to the wire as raw HTML. Doing this on the client is going to be difficult unless you can bundle a JSX compiler on the front-end.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do what I want, with the caveat that it's somewhat manual, and potentially dangerous. However, in my case, I'm creating a blog/CMS for a very limited audience, and the concern about users potentially inserting harmful content is non-existent.

My approach ended up using `html-to-react` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react). `Html-to-react` accepts a string (containing raw HTML markup), and transforms it into a proper React component. By default, its `parse()` method doesn't properly handle React components (it just turns them into lower-case-named html elements). However, the library has a `parseWithInstructions`, which allows you to control how individual nodes in the component are rendered.

In my case, I want to enable certain React components to be rendered. One of those is my `ExternalLink` component. What follows is the method I use to transform some user-entered raw HTML into a React component that properly rendered my components.

```
updatePreview() {

    // Combine the user-entered CSS and the user-entered HTML into a single string.
    let outputPreview = "<div><style>" + this.state.cssValue + "</style><div>" + this.state.inputValue + "</div></div>";

    let htmlToReactParser = new HtmlToReact.Parser();
    let processNodeDefinitions = new HtmlToReact.ProcessNodeDefinitions(React);
    let processingInstructions = [
        {
            // Custom <ExternalLink> processing
            shouldProcessNode: function (node) {
                return node.name === 'externallink';
            },
            processNode: function (node, children) {
                let attribs = node.attribs;
                return <ExternalLink {...attribs}>{children}</ExternalLink>
            }
        },
        {
            // Anything else
            shouldProcessNode: function (node) {
                return true;
            },
            processNode: processNodeDefinitions.processDefaultNode
        }];

    // Convert the HTML into a React component
    let reactComponent = htmlToReactParser.parseWithInstructions(outputPreview, () => true,
        processingInstructions);


    // Now that we have a react component, we set it to the state.
    // Our render() method includes a "{this.state.outputPreview}", which causes the
    // component to be rendered.
    this.setState({outputPreview: reactComponent, refreshPreviewTimer: null});
}
```

Note that `outputString` in the first line of the method will contain some raw text like this:

```
"<div>
  <style></style>
  <div>
    <p>Here's a link:<p>
    <ExternalLink url="http://www.google.com">Google</ExternalLink>
  </div>
</div>"
```

There are some approaches I'll take to generalize this approach more, using a dictionary of strings to enable support for a wider range of Components. I'll also look at some approach to automatically importing the desired Component. (Currently, I'm manually importing all supported components.)

So, all credit goes to the author of `html-to-react`, though I may encourage him to include an example of rendering child components.

Comment: Thank you! I need to collapse quoted text and this trick is very helpful for me.